# Join on two tables - display data where there is no matching record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that I'm trying to do a join on....the structure of my tables looks like this...

```
tbl1
NoClient          ApptDate         Status         
1234              12/22/2016       A
3555              1/23/2017        A
3495              12/23/2016       A


tbl2
NoClient          ApptDate  
1234              12/22/2016
3555              1/24/2017
```

So I'm trying to join these two tables on `NoClient` and `ApptDate`.

My goal is to see all records from `tbl1` - where there is no matching record in `tbl2` (`ApptDate` and `Noclient`)

Desired end result in this case

```
NoClient      AppDate
3555          1/23/2017        
3495          12/23/2016
```

`NoClient = 3555` has a corresponding record in `tbl2` however, the `ApptDate` is not the same. `NoClient = 3495` doesn't have a corresponding record all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for this:

```
Select      T1.NoClient, T1.ApptDate
From        Tbl1    T1
Left Join   Tbl2    T2  On  T1.NoClient = T2.NoClient
                        And T1.ApptDate = T2.ApptDate
Where       T2.NoClient Is Null
```

Alternatively, you can also use a `WHERE NOT EXISTS`:

```
Select  T1.NoClient, T1.ApptDate
From    Tbl1    T1
Where Not Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    Tbl2    T2
    Where   T1.NoClient = T2.NoClient
    And     T1.ApptDate = T2.ApptDate
)
```

Comment: I believe your first query will return the opposite of what OP wants - the matching record(s).

Comment: @Tricky12 The `Where T2.NoClient Is Null` would filter out any matches.

Comment: Yeah that's right, was thinking of it backwards when I first looked at it ha.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

SELECT * FROM Table1

WHERE (NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT * FROM Table2

WHERE(Table1.NoClient = Table2.NoClient) 
AND (Table1.ApptDate = Table2.ApptDate )))